# Security issues when displaying external images

Tags: php, security

I've made a "wall" script that analysed an url and get some datas from this url.

I want to display images from this url to get a thumb.

So my question  is :

Is it possible to be 100% safe when displaying an image from an external content ?

For exemple Facebook use a " safe_image.php?urlOfThePicture "

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to be 100% safe when displaying an image from an external content ?

In general, you can't be 100% safe with anything. However, you can do as much as possible to protect yourself and make compromise difficult.

The biggest danger here is probably CSRF. If you just display the image copying its original URL, you can easily grab a malicious URL that claims to be an image but actually sends a request to an arbitrary vulnerable site (your mail, your bank, etc). Facebook deals with this by actually creating a copy of each image uploaded so the image displayed to your browser is always safe.

If you have a program that downloads the image and generates thumbnails, you need to be sure that the program can deal with corrupt (malicious) images, otherwise that could be targeted and compromised.